# В чем причина ошибки с fancyBox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

При расположении нескольких идентичных ссылок на странице перестает корректно работать открытие PopUp с инлайн-контентом: появляется на секунду и исчезает, причем, остается затемненный фон.

Если ссылка одна, то все ок.
Ссылка:

```
<a data-fancybox="forms" data-src="#order-popup" href="javascript:;"></a>
```

Инициализация:

```
 $('[data-fancybox="forms"]').fancybox({
        infobar: false,
        touch: {
            vertical: false, 
            momentum: false
        }
    });
```

Скрытый блок:

```
<div class="order-popup hide" id="order-popup">Содержимое</div>
```

При расположении нескольких ссылок в адресной строке уже не `site.ru/#forms`, а `site.ru/#forms-1 site.ru/#forms-2` и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Из оф источника, имена класов надо чтоб были прикручены, только так он их групирует вместе... Вот держите пример.

> If you want to use the same script for all your images/elements then
>   use classes instead.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
 /* Apply fancybox to multiple items */
 $('.grouped_elements').fancybox({
  'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
  'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
  'speedIn'  : 600, 
  'speedOut'  : 200, 
  'overlayShow' : false
 });
 
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>

<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="http://expres.ua/gfx/news/gugl_10.png">1</a>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="http://expres.ua/gfx/news/gugl_10.png">1</a>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="http://expres.ua/gfx/news/gugl_10.png">1</a>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="http://expres.ua/gfx/news/gugl_10.png">1</a>

<div class="order-popup hide" id="order-popup">Содержимое</div>
```